# If "hexa-" is a prefix representing six

Tags: prefixes

Why does the word "hexadecimal" have the prefix "hexa-" if it has a base of 16, not 6?

Comment: hexa = 6, deci = 10. seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: I find it odd because http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senary is the numeral system with a base of 6.

Comment: @tenfour: write it as an answer :)

Comment: I still don't see the obviousness.

Comment: @c00lryguy, at the top of the wikipedia article you link, the article explains (one reasoning for) the choice of Senary over "heximal", the corollary of hexadecimal and decimal: "The name heximal is also valid for such a numeral system, but is deprecated to avoid confusion with the more often used hexadecimal number base, colloquially known as 'hex'."

Comment: Awesome site outlining greek and latin numerical prefixes (both of which come into play here): http://phrontistery.info/numbers.html

Comment: *hexadecimal* is a [hybrid word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word), a mixture of Greek and Latin.  Perhaps it would better be Greek (*dekexial*?) or Latin (*sedecimal*).

Comment: @Tao: Yeah that site is quite correct.

Comment: @Henry: Agreed. The Greek ordinal number would be *hekkaidekatos*, the English prefix probably *heccaedeca-*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hexa-** is the Greek prefix for the number six, from *hex*, "six"; cf. *hexagon*, *hexameter*, *hexad*, etc.

**Decimus** is the Latin ordinal number "tenth"; cf. *decimate*, *decimal*.

This hybrid construction *hexadecimal* is strange but often seen in English to mean "sixteenth" or "pertaining to sixteen". It does not exist in either Latin or Greek, of course.

In Latin, it would be **sedecimus**, "sixteenth", leading to English *sedecimal*.

In Greek, in would be **hekkaidekatos**, "sixteenth", possibly leading to English *heccaedecatic*; but derivations of such polysyllabic Greek numbers are rarely used in English. The prefix would be *heccaedeca-*, as in a *heccaedeca(h)edron*, a polyhedron with sixteen surfaces.

Comment: Back in those times, little importance was given to numbers beyond around 12.  For this reason in english, numbers one through twelve are all unique names while a pattern emerges afterds (thir*teen* four*teen* fif*teen* etc.).  They came afterwards.  Consequently, the typical way to handle such ideas was to sum two such numbers to define a larger number.  In fact, "thirteen" "fourteen" "fifteen" essentially only mean "3 10" "4 10" "5 10".

Comment: @Neil: True. And 11 and 12 also come from one-ten and two-ten in Latin (*un-decim*) and Greek (*hen-deka*). It is just the Germanic languages that use one-left and two-left ("one left if you remove ten", or something like that).

Answer (score 10):

If *decimal* is "ten-ly", *hexadecimal* is "six-ten-ly", or "sixteenly".

Comment: Ahh yes, this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

The prefix “hexa-” originally means six, it's “hexadecim-” that means sixteen. (Latin and greek had constructions similar to English for numbers between 13 and 19.) In computer-related usage, base 16 is very common, so the prefix for 16 has come to be systematically abbreviated “hex-” or “hexa-”. Since base 6 is never used, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: I've been using base 6 ever since I lost four fingers in a taxidermy accident.

Comment: It makes sense that the prefix is *hexadecim* and not *hexa*. After all, if the root was *decimal* then we'd say *decidecimal* for base 10, no?

Comment: @ScottMitchell: Strictly speaking, this should be “decaxi-” (Greek) or “sedecim-” (Latin).

Comment: @Gilles: Where did you get *decaxi-*? Is that new Greek for *tenth*, perhaps? *Sixteenth* would be *heccaidecatos* in Ancient Greek; *hexadecatos* might exist in later Greek, though I doubt it.

Comment: @Cerberus: Erm, yes, that was modern Greek, oops. I just wanted to nitpick on the Latin-Greek mixture and goofed.

Comment: @Gilles: Yeah I know the feeling, happens to me too. I had to look this one up in several dictionaries, and it took me some time to check and double check... I absolutely agree about the hybrid construction.

Answer (score 4):

Because "sexadecimal" would be considered too rude for IBM in the 50s.

Knuth says that it should be "senidenary." (The art of computer programming vol. 2 Seminumerical Algorithms p200.)

Comment: Hmm, but Latin would be “sedecim-”, not “sexadecim-”. So that IBM story is probably apocryphal.