# Quadruped is to four-legged animal as ___ is to six-legged animal?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A creature which walks on two legs can be referred to as biped; bi- meaning *two*.

A creature which walks on four legs can be referred to as quadruped; quad- meaning *four*.

What is the corresponding word for a six-legged creature?

Comment: In principle it would probably be a [***hexapod***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hexapod). But apart from the specific case of *a six-legged arthropod of the class Insecta (formerly **Hexapoda**)*, there aren't many examples, so you wouldn't need it often enough to justify confusing readers with an unfamiliar term. Just call it a six-legged creature.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Unless you happen to be a science fiction writer :-)

Comment: Are they called "insect"?

Comment: Quadruplets -> Sextuplets. Why not Quadrupeds -> Sextupeds?

Comment: @JEL - just for clarity, what details do you think are missing? Doesn't hexapod answer OP question?

Comment: @Josh, 'hexapod' does provide an answer, but not the best answer nor the complete answer because the question takes the form of 'X1 is to Y1 as X2 is to Y2'. I think the whole answer is worth having, partly because of what Webster said in 1828 about the words (that last is not necessary for the bonus, but would be nice to include).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Hexapod](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hexapod) (n., plural hexapods):

> - Any organism or being with six legs.

(The Free Dictionary)

***[Hexapod](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hexapod)*** (n.) etymology:

> - "six-footed insect," 1660s, from Modern Latin hexapod-, stem of hexapodus, ***from Greek hex "six" (see six) + Greek pod-,*** stem of pous "foot" (from PIE root *ped- "foot"). Greek hexapous (adj.) was used only with reference to poetic meter. As an adjective from 1856.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Robots with six legs are also called hexapods.

Comment: Any insight on why the ending changed from *-ped* to *-pod*?

Comment: @R.M. Yeah interesting shift from Latin to Greek alright!

Comment: Apparently a preying mantis is a *hexapod* but usually seen as a *quadruped*  as it usually does not use its grasping forelegs to walk (though it can)

Comment: Hexapodia is the key insight.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Shouldn't it be sextuped?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, if you're using quadruped to refer to a four-legged creature, the word would indeed be sexaped. However, English, being a hosh-posh of other languages, uses the word hexapod.

Comment: We also use quadropod. I think either hex- word would be OK in terms of being understood.

Comment: “*hosh posh*”??? Do you mean ***hodgepodge***?

Comment: @Jim: Some people would say that the correct spelling is "hotchpotch".  The word seems to be particularly prone to mutation. That said, I haven't seen this specific variant before.

Answer (score 2):

Well, people balk at the risky-sounding sexaped, so you need to switch to Greek and use hexapod.  Doing the same for 4- and 2-legged creatures would result in a tetrapod and a dipod.  Problem with those are that they are reminiscent of a tripod, a clearly inanimate object.

All those foreign language terms come with associations reducing the applicability of the originally rather generic meaning.

Why not switch back to English and use "six-legged"?  Works for insects (which is Latin for grooved beasts) as well as furniture.

Answer (score 1):

### *Hexapod, Hexaped, Sexaped, Sexiped*...—Take your pick.

I think requiring a single word for this concept is a bit unnecessary. (As user256320 says, you can just use "six-legged" or "six-footed"). But setting that aside, it's a bit tricky to say what "the" corresponding word is.

I am not a Classics expert, so some of what I say in this answer may be incorrect. If you care about forming a word in accordance with Latin/Greek precedent, probably it's best to ask the experts at the [Latin Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com), or even to ask someone outside of the Stack Exchange network (gasp!) whose judgement you trust.

If you don't care about that, you can choose between any of "hexapod," "sexapod", "hexaped", "sexaped", "sexiped", "sextuped", etc. based on whatever criteria you do care about—if you want more help with that here, it would help to make it explicit what those criteria are.

(JEL in a comment references an entry in Webster's 1828 arguing for "[hexaped](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/hexaped)" on the basis of uniformity with "quadruped" and "centiped". That's fine, but there's no inherent reason why anyone has to care about uniformity. Some people have an aversion to compounds that blend Latin and Greek elements, and might reject "hexaped" for this reason.)

My own preference would roughly be as follows, from my favored to least favored options: *hexapod, hexaped/sexiped, sextuped*, other variants.

#### Hexapod: the most common word

As other answers and comments have pointed out, the word "**hexapod**" from Greek is the most common single word for something with six legs. I think Josh's answer is therefore quite satisfactory. Many people think frequency of usage is a good criterion for word choice.

#### The *-pod* and *-ped* words, and Greek and Latin compounds

- We have other "-pod" words from Greek: the most common are *tripod* and *tetrapod.* These are based on Greek compounds ending in *pous,* the Greek word for "foot". There are also compounds where the initial element is not from a numeral like *arthropod* and *gastropod.* Some other words that ultimately come from Greek *pous,* but have developed to end in different ways in present-day English are *octopus* and *polyp,* and the plural *antipodes.*
- From Latin, we have *biped* and *quadruped.* These are based on Latin compounds ending in *pes,* the Latin word for "foot". With slightly different spelling and pronunciation of the second element, we have *centipede* and *millipede.* (*Centiped* and *milliped* do exist as less common variants: someone who values consistency more than following common usage should perhaps consider choosing to use these forms.)

As far as I know, neither set of words exists in a generally-agreed-upon complete series of words for animals with *n* numbers of legs. Each of these words has its own history leading to its present-day use and understood meaning. For example, *tripod* is usually used to refer to inanimate objects (as few living organisms have three legs), while *tetrapod* is used in biology to refer to a specific group of animals, not all of which have four legs (humans and birds are biological tetrapods). Although the prefix *milli-* comes from the Latin word for "thousand," the animals we call *millipedes* have fewer than a thousand legs.

### Compounds in Greek, in Latin, and in English from Greek and Latin

One thing that I have read is that compounding was not as common or productive in Classical Latin as it was in Classical Greek. Latin compounds are often somewhat artificial and belong to a learned register of the language; or they are just two separate words written together, like *benefacio* = *bene facio* "do good (literally "do well"). To me, this suggests that it's a more "risky" matter to coin words based on Latin than it is to make new words based on Greek. But that's just how I feel about it.

As I mentioned above, some people like to avoid forming or using compound words in English that have been made by combining Latin and Greek elements. Of course, many of these are too well-established to avoid, like *television,* but it's a matter of opinion whether that fact renders the whole endeavor pointless. See e.g. [Is there a reason to use "mono" over "uni"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39800), [Prefixes milli- and cent- used for years](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134089/prefixes-milli-and-cent-used-for-years).

### Latin prefixes for "six": *sexa-/sexi-/sexu-*? *sexti-/sextu-*?

#### General formation of Latin compounds: connecting *-i-*

In Latin, the elements of a compound are usually "connected" with the vowel *i,* for some complicated historical reasons that I am not qualified to explain (but in brief, my understanding is that regular sound changes and analogy both played a role). This however is often not present when the second element of the compound starts with a vowel.

Another complication: sometimes *u* was used in place of *i* when the following consonant had a labial place of articulation, like *b* or *p.* This explains the *u* in the combining form *quadru-,* a variant of *quadri-* that is found in present-day English words like *quadru**p**ed* and *quadru**p**le.* But the use of *u* vs. *i* doesn't seem to be particularly regular, as we also have *centipede* and *millipede* mentioned above, and *quadripartite* (which does apparently have a variant *quadrupartite*).

#### Latin *six* words

The Latin word for "six" was *sex.*

A search of the Perseus Digital Library turned up no compound words in Latin with "sexi-" as a prefix.

However, the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) does have an entry for *sexi-* as an English prefix, and this entry mentions the form "sexiped". It says

> < classical Latin *sex* six (see *sex-* comb. form) + *-i-* connective, perhaps after *quadri-* comb. form, *septi-* comb. form1, etc. Compare *sex-* comb. form, *sexti-* comb. form, and also *hexa-* comb. form.
>   Formations are found from the first half of the 19th cent. (compare *sexiped* n. ).
>
> Some formations have parallels in *sex-* comb. form, and some have parallels in *hexa-* comb. form.

Although the prefix precedes a labial consonant in the word "sexiped", for some reason the "i" doesn't seem to mutate to "u" as in *quadruped.* I don't know if there is any theoretical way to rule out *sexuped* as a possibility.

#### *sex-* and *sexti-*

The OED entry quoted above references two other similar prefixes, *sex-* (with no linking vowel) and *sexti-* (from *sextus*).

- "Sexped" does in fact seem to have been used at leat once, in *[Systema Vegetabilium](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_XXdIAAAAYAAJ#page/n505/mode/2up/search/sexped),* but it is certainly extremely rare.
- *Sexti-* is apparently derived from the Latin word for "sixth", *sextus.* Although it doesn't make much sense to me to use an ordinal number as the base of a word meaning "six-legged", the meaning of *sexti-* seems to have broadened compared to its origin, as the OED says it is "Attested in a small number of formations of the 16th and 17th centuries [...] forming adjectives and nouns with the sense 'having six, sixfold'". The OED's examples are *sextipartite* (divided into six parts), *sextisection* (division into six parts), *sextipartition.* It is also present in the variant form *sextu-* in the word *sextuple,* and the less common *[sextuplex](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sextuplex).*

  While I haven't been able to find much evidence indicating that "sextiped" is used as a word meaning "having six legs", "sextuped" does seem to have a small but definite amount of use, judging from Google results. (I would guess that people are going on the analogy *quadruple* : *sextuple* :: *quadruped* : "sextuped": in fact, I see a [comment by Eric Duminil](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409242/quadruped-is-to-four-legged-animal-as-is-to-six-legged-animal/409243#comment975158_409242) made that analogy already.)

#### The mysterious *sexa-*(?)

For some reason, many people seem to have the intuition that a prefix *sexa-* exists corresponding to the number "six". I somewhat suspect that this is simply a confusion of Latin *sex* and Greek *hexa-,* but it's possible that there is more to it. I haven't able to find any good evidence of a Latin origin for *sexa-* as a prefix, though.

There are Latin words starting with starting with "sexa", but as far as I can tell,they are all either compounds of "sex-" plus a word starting with "a" (as in "sexangulus"), or seem to be composed of "sex-" plus a suffix starting with "a" (as in the word *sexaginta* "sixty"—compare *quadraginta* "forty", or *sexatrus* "the sixth day after the Ides"—compare *quinquatrus, decimatrus, septimatrus, triatrus*). So, I would say that I don't know of any convincing evidence demonstrating that "sexa-" was used in Latin as a combining suffix of the same type as *quadri-/quadru-* or *centi-.*

A [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix) asserts that "sexa-" is one of the "Latin" "number prefixes in English", but it's not clear what it means by  this and that specific piece of information has no citation (the page as a whole cites the OED, Carl Darling Buck's  *Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin,* and Sihler's *New Comparative Grammar of Greek and Latin*, so maybe one of these sources has it, or maybe not).

Also relevant: the supposedly Latinate form "[sexadecimal](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/23320/77227)" as an equivalent to "hexadecimal", mentioned in the linked answer and disputed by Gilles' comment below ("but Latin would be “sedecim-”, not “sexadecim-”").

The OED does not have an entry for "sexa-" nor the word "sexaped". That said, a word doesn't have to be in the OED to be used. As I said, it's really a matter of opinion—and if you want an educated opinion about which word is most "correct", you'd have to ask someone with an education that's relevant to whatever your idea of "correct" is.